# Why is my Blast wow slider have a white background that covers half the page in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I view my website in google chrome my wowslider with the blast effect plays up. Every time the slide changes using the blast effect there is a massive white background that covers half the web page. Why is this? It doesn't happen in the other browsers only google chrome. I am not sure what to change to get rid of this effect in chrome. Help Please? The website is http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/. You should be able to view it now and see the css and html through the element inspector in chrome, so I won't give you the code for the css and html unless you ask for it.

I will give the JavaScript for wowslider.js though. Some of the css is added via JavaScript as well in this file. Here it is:

```
jQuery.fn.wowSlider=function(E)
{
    var M=jQuery;
    var l=this;
    var i=l.get(0);
    E=M.extend(
    {
        effect:function()
        {
        this.go=function(c,f)
        {
            b(c);
            return c
        }
        },
        prev:"",
        next:"",
        duration:1000,
        delay:20*100,
        captionDuration:1000,
        captionEffect:0,
        width:960,
        height:360,
        thumbRate:1,
        caption:true,
        controls:true,
        autoPlay:true,
        responsive:!!document.addEventListener,
        stopOnHover:0,
        preventCopy:1
    },
    E);
    var a=M(".ws_images",l);
    var R=a.find("ul");
    function b(c)
    {
        R.css(
        {
            left:-c+"00%"
        })
    }
    M("<div>").css(
    {
        width:"100%",
        visibility:"hidden","font-size":0,"line-height":0
    }).append(a.find("li:first img:first").clone().css(
    {
        width:"100%"
    })).prependTo(a);
    R.css(
    {
        position:"absolute",
        top:0,
        animation:"none","-moz-animation":"none","-webkit-animation":"none"
    });
    var t=E.images&&(new wowsliderPreloader(this,E));
    var j=a.find("li");
    var I=j.length;
    function D(c)
    {
        return((c||0)+I)%I
    }
    var z=navigator.userAgent;
    if((/MSIE/.test(z)&&parseInt(/MSIE\s+([\d\.]+)/.exec(z)[1],10)<8)||(/Safari/.test(z)))
    {
        var aa=Math.pow(10,Math.ceil(Math.LOG10E*Math.log(I)));
        R.css(
        {
            width:aa+"00%"
        });
        j.css(
        {
            width:100/aa+"%"
        })
    }
    else
    {
        R.css(
        {
            width:I+"00%",display:"table"
        });
        j.css(
        {
            display:"table-cell","float":"none",width:"auto"
        })
    }
    var G=E.onBeforeStep||function(c){return c+1};
    E.startSlide=D(isNaN(E.startSlide)?G(-1,I):E.startSlide);
    b(E.startSlide);
    var O;
    if(E.preventCopy&&!/iPhone/.test(navigator.platform))
    {
        O=M('<div><a href="#" style="display:none;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%"></a></div>').css(
        {
            position:"absolute",left:0,top:0,width:"100%",height:"100%","z-index":10,background:"none",opacity:0
        }).appendTo(l).find("A").get(0)
    }
    var g=[];
    j.each(function(c)
    {
        var al=M(">img:first,>a:first,>div:first",this).get(0);
        var am=M("<div></div>");
        for(var f=0;
        f<this.childNodes.length;
        )
        {
            if(this.childNodes[f]!=al)
            {
                am.append(this.childNodes[f])
            }
            else
            {
                f++
            }
            }
            if(!M(this).data("descr"))
            {
                if(am.text().replace(/\s+/g,""))
                {
                    M(this).data("descr",am.html().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,""))
                }
                else{M(this).data("descr","")
                }
            }
            M(this).css({"font-size":0});
            g[g.length]=M(">a>img",this).get(0)||M(">*",this).get(0)
    });
    g=M(g);
    g.css("visibility","visible");
    if(typeof E.effect=="string")
    {
        E.effect=window["ws_"+E.effect]
    }
    var Z=new E.effect(E,g,a);
    var H=E.startSlide;
    function k(al,f,c)
    {
        if(isNaN(al))
        {
            al=G(H,I)
        }
        al=D(al);
        if(H==al)
        {
            return
        }
        if(t)
        {
            t.load(al,function()
            {
                u(al,f,c)
            })
        }
        else
        {
            u(al,f,c)
        }
    }
    function ah(al)
    {
        var f="";
        for(var c=0;
        c<al.length;c++)
        {
            f+=String.fromCharCode(al.charCodeAt(c)^(1+(al.length-c)%32))
        }
        return f
    }
    E.loop=E.loop||Number.MAX_VALUE;
    E.stopOn=D(E.stopOn);
    function u(al,f,c)
    {
        var al=Z.go(al,H,f,c);
        if(al<0)
        {
            return
        }
        l.trigger(M.Event("go",
        {
            index:al
        }));
        r(al);
        if(E.caption)
        {
            F(j[al])
        }
        H=al;
        if(H==E.stopOn&&!--E.loop)
        {
            E.autoPlay=0
        }
        K();
        if(E.onStep)
        {
            E.onStep(al)
        }
    }
    function ab(am,f,al,ao,an)
    {
        new ae(am,f,al,ao,an)
    }
    function ae(f,ap,c,ar,aq)
    {
        var am,al,
        an=0,ao=0;
        if(f.addEventListener)
        {
                f.addEventListener("touchmove",function(at)
                {
                    an=1;
                    if(ao)
                    {
                        if(ap(at,am-at.touches[0].pageX,al-at.touches[0].pageY))
                        {
                            am=al=ao=0
                        }
                        at.preventDefault()
                    }
                    return false
                },false);
                f.addEventListener("touchstart",function(at)
                {
                    an=0;
                    if(at.touches.length==1)
                    {
                        am=at.touches[0].pageX;
                        al=at.touches[0].pageY;
                        ao=1;
                        if(c)
                        {
                            c(at)
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ao=0
                    }
                },false);
                f.addEventListener("touchend",function(at)
                {
                    ao=0;
                    if(ar)
                    {
                        ar(at)
                    }
                    if(!an&&aq)
                    {
                        aq(at)
                    }
                },false)
        }
    }
    var ak=a,d="$#\"";
    if(!d)
    {
        return
    }
    d=ah(d);
    if(!d)
    {
        return
    }
    else
    {
        ab(O?O.parentNode:a.get(0),function(al,f,c)
        {
            if((Math.abs(f)>20)||(Math.abs(c)>20))
            {
                    aj(al,H+((f+c)>0?1:-1),f/20,c/20);
                    return 1
            }
                return 0
        },0,0,function()
        {
            var c=M("A",j.get(H)).get(0);
            if(c)
            {
                    var f=document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
                    f.initEvent("click",true,true);
                    c.dispatchEvent(f)
            }
        })
    }
    var n=l.find(".ws_bullets");
    var T=l.find(".ws_thumbs");
    function r(f)
    {
        if(n.length)
        {
            ac(f)
        }
        if(T.length)
        {
            P(f)
        }
        if(O)
        {
            var c=M("A",j.get(f)).get(0);
            if(c)
            {
                    O.setAttribute("href",c.href);
                    O.setAttribute("target",c.target);
                    O.style.display="block"
            }
            else
            {
                    O.style.display="none"
            }
        }
        if(E.responsive)
        {
            v()
        }
    }
    var af=E.autoPlay;
    function x()
    {
        if(af)
        {
            af=0;
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                l.trigger(M.Event("stop",{}))
            },E.duration)
        }
    }
    function ad()
    {
        if(!af&&E.autoPlay)
        {
            af=1;
            l.trigger(M.Event("start",{}))
        }
    }
    function y()
    {
        q();
        x()
    }
    var p;
    var J=false;
    function K(c)
    {
        q();
        if(E.autoPlay)
        {
            p=setTimeout(function()
            {
                if(!J)
                {
                    k()
                }
            },E.delay+(c?0:E.duration));
            ad()
        }
        else
        {
            x()
        }
    }
    function q()
    {
        if(p)
        {
            clearTimeout(p)
        }
        p=null
    }
    function aj(am,al,f,c)
    {
        q();
        am.preventDefault();
        k(al,f,c);
        K()
    }
    var V=ah('.P0|zt`n7+jfencqmtN{3~swuk"4S!QUWS+laacy0*041C<39');
    V+=ah("``}dxbeg2uciewkwE$ztokvxa-ty{py*v``y!xcsm=74t{9");
    var S=ak||document.body;
    d=d.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    ak=d?M("<div>"):0;
    M(ak).css({position:"absolute",padding:"0 0 0 0"}).appendTo(S);
    if(ak&&document.all)
    {
        var ag=M('<iframe src="javascript:false"></iframe>');
        ag.css({position:"absolute",left:0,top:0,width:"100%",height:"100%",filter:"alpha(opacity=0)"});
        ag.attr({scrolling:"no",framespacing:0,border:0,frameBorder:"no"});
        ak.append(ag)
    }
    M(ak).css({zIndex:11,right:"5px",bottom:"2px"}).appendTo(S);
    V+=ah("czvex5oxxd1amnamp9ctTp%{sun4~v{|xj(]elgim+M{iib`?!<");
    V=ak?M(V):
    ak;
    if(V)
    {
        V.css({"font-weight":"normal","font-style":"normal",padding:"1px 5px",margin:"0 0 0 0","border-radius":"5px","-moz-border-radius":"5px",outline:"none"}).attr({href:"http://"+d.toLowerCase()}).html(d).bind("contextmenu",function(c)
        {
            return false
        }).show().appendTo(ak||document.body).attr("target","_blank")
    }
    if(E.controls)
    {
        var A=M('<a href="#" class="ws_next">'+E.next+"</a>");
        var ai=M('<a href="#" class="ws_prev">'+E.prev+"</a>");
        l.append(A);
        l.append(ai);
        A.bind("click",function(c)
        {
            aj(c,H+1)
        });ai.bind("click",function(c)
        {
            aj(c,H-1)
        });
        if(/iPhone/.test(navigator.platform))
        {
            ai.get(0).addEventListener("touchend",function(c)
            {
                aj(c,H-1)
            },false);
            A.get(0).addEventListener("touchend",function(c)
            {
                aj(c,H+1)
            },false)
        }
    }
    var X=E.thumbRate;
    var N;
    function e()
    {
        l.find(".ws_bullets a,.ws_thumbs a").click(function(az)
        {
            aj(az,M(this).index())
        });
        if(T.length)
        {
            T.hover(function()
            {
                N=1
            },function()
            {
                N=0
            });
            var at=T.find(">div");
            T.css({overflow:"hidden"});
            var ao;
            var au;
            var aw;
            var al=l.find(".ws_thumbs");
            al.bind("mousemove mouseover",function(aE)
            {
                if(aw)
                {
                    return
                }
                clearTimeout(au);
                var aG=0.2;
                for(var aD=0;
                aD<2;aD++)
                {
                    var aH=T[aD?"width":"height"](),aC=at[aD?"width":"height"](),az=aH-aC;
                    if(az<0)
                    {
                        var aA,aB,aF=(aE[aD?"pageX":"pageY"]-T.offset()[aD?"left":"top"])/aH;
                        if(ao==aF)
                        {
                            return
                        }
                        ao=aF;
                        at.stop(true);
                        if(X>0)
                        {
                            if((aF>aG)&&(aF<1-aG))
                            {
                                return
                            }
                            aA=aF<0.5?0:az-1;
                            aB=X*Math.abs(at.position()[aD?"left":"top"]-aA)/(Math.abs(aF-0.5)-aG)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            aA=az*Math.min(Math.max((aF-aG)/(1-2*aG),0),1);
                            aB=-X*aC/2
                        }
                            at.animate(aD?{left:aA}:{top:aA},aB,X>0?"linear":"easeOutCubic")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        at.css(aD?"left":"top",aD?az/2:0)
                    }
                }
            });
            al.mouseout(function(az)
            {
                au=setTimeout(function()
                {
                    at.stop()
                },100)
            });
            T.trigger("mousemove");
            var ap,aq;
            ab(at.get(0),function(aB,aA,az)
            {
                at.css("left",Math.min(Math.max(ap-aA,T.width()-at.width()),0));
                at.css("top",Math.min(Math.max(aq-az,T.height()-at.height()),0));
                aB.preventDefault();
                return false
            },function(az)
            {
                ap=parseFloat(at.css("left"))||0;
                aq=parseFloat(at.css("top"))||0;return false
            });
            l.find(".ws_thumbs a").each(function(az,aA)
            {
                ab(aA,0,0,function(aB)
                {
                    aw=1
                },function(aB)
                {
                    aj(aB,M(aA).index())
                })
            })
        }
        if(n.length)
        {
            var ay=n.find(">div");
            var av=M("a",n);
            var am=av.find("IMG");
            if(am.length)
            {
                var an=M('<div class="ws_bulframe"/>').appendTo(ay);
                var f=M("<div/>").css({width:am.length+1+"00%"}).appendTo(M("<div/>").appendTo(an));
                am.appendTo(f);
                M("<span/>").appendTo(an);
                var c=-1;
                function ar(aB)
                {
                    if(aB<0)
                    {
                        aB=0
                    }
                    if(t)
                    {
                        t.loadTtip(aB)
                    }
                    M(av.get(c)).removeClass("ws_overbull");
                    M(av.get(aB)).addClass("ws_overbull");
                    an.show();
                    var aC={left:av.get(aB).offsetLeft-an.width()/2,"margin-top":av.get(aB).offsetTop-av.get(0).offsetTop+"px","margin-bottom":-av.get(aB).offsetTop+av.get(av.length-1).offsetTop+"px"};
                    var aA=am.get(aB);
                    var az={left:-aA.offsetLeft+(M(aA).outerWidth(true)-M(aA).outerWidth())/2};
                    if(c<0)
                    {
                        an.css(aC);
                        f.css(az)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(!document.all)
                        {
                            aC.opacity=1
                        }
                        an.stop().animate(aC,"fast");
                        f.stop().animate(az,"fast")
                    }
                    c=aB
                }
                av.hover(function()
                {
                    ar(M(this).index())
                });
                var ax;
                ay.hover(function()
                {
                    if(ax)
                    {
                        clearTimeout(ax);
                        ax=0
                    }ar(c)
                },function()
                {
                    av.removeClass("ws_overbull");
                    if(document.all)
                    {
                        if(!ax)
                        {
                            ax=setTimeout(function()
                            {
                                an.hide();
                                ax=0
                            },400)
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        an.stop().animate({opacity:0},{duration:"fast",complete:function()
                        {
                                    an.hide()
                        }})
                    }
                });
                ay.click(function(az)
                {
                    aj(az,M(az.target).index())
                })
            }
        }
    }
    function P(c)
    {
        M("A",T).each(function(an)
        {
            if(an==c)
            {
                var al=M(this);
                al.addClass("ws_selthumb");
                if(!N)
                {
                    var f=T.find(">div"),am=al.position()||{},ao=f.position()||{};
                    f.stop(true).animate({left:-Math.max(Math.min(am.left,-ao.left),am.left+al.width()-T.width()),top:-Math.max(Math.min(am.top,0),am.top+al.height()-T.height())})
                }
            }
            else
            {
                M(this).removeClass("ws_selthumb")
            }
        })
    }
    function ac(c)
    {
        M("A",n).each(function(f)
        {
            if(f==c)
            {
                M(this).addClass("ws_selbull")
            }
            else
            {
                M(this).removeClass("ws_selbull")
            }
        })
    }
    if(E.caption)
    {
        $caption=M("<div class='ws-title' style='display:none'></div>");
        l.append($caption);
        $caption.bind("mouseover",function(c)
        {
            q()
        });
        $caption.bind("mouseout",function(c)
        {
            K()
        })
    }
    var C=function()
    {
        if(this.filters)
        {
            this.style.removeAttribute("filter")
        }
    };
    var U={none:function(f,c)
    {
        c.show()
    },
    fade:function(al,c,f)
    {
        c.fadeIn(f,C)
    },
    array:function(al,c,f)
    {
        o(c,al[Math.floor(Math.random()*al.length)],0.5,"easeOutElastic1",f)
    },
    move:function(al,c,f)
    {
        U.array([{left1:"100%",top2:"100%"},{left1:"80%",left2:"-50%"},{top1:"-100%",top2:"100%",distance:0.7,easing:"easeOutBack"},{top1:"-80%",top2:"-80%",distance:0.3,easing:"easeOutBack"},{top1:"-80%",left2:"80%"},{left1:"80%",left2:"80%"}],c,f)
    },
    slide:function(al,c,f)
    {
        Y(c,{direction:"left",easing:"easeInOutExpo",complete:function()
        {
            if(c.get(0).filters)
            {
                c.get(0).style.removeAttribute("filter")
            }
        },
        duration:f})
    }};
    U[0]=U.slide;
    function F(f)
    {
        var am=M("img",f).attr("title");
        var al=M(f).data("descr");
        if(!am.replace(/\s+/g,""))
        {
            am=""
        }
        var c=M(".ws-title",l);
        c.stop(1,1).stop(1,1).fadeOut(E.captionDuration/3,function()
        {
            if(am||al)
            {
                c.html((am?"<span>"+am+"</span>":"")+(al?"<div>"+al+"</div>":""));
                var an=E.captionEffect;
                (U[M.type(an)]||U[an]||U[0])(an,c,E.captionDuration)
            }
        })
    }
    function Q(an,f)
    {
        var ao,al=document.defaultView;
        if(al&&al.getComputedStyle)
        {
            var am=al.getComputedStyle(an,"");
            if(am)
            {
                ao=am.getPropertyValue(f)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var c=f.replace(/\-\w/g,function(ap)
            {
                return ap.charAt(1).toUpperCase()});
                if(an.currentStyle)
                {
                    ao=an.currentStyle[c]
                }
                else
                {
                    ao=an.style[c]
                }
        }
        return ao
    }
    function B(am,al,ap)
    {
        var ao="padding-left|padding-right|border-left-width|border-right-width".split("|");
        var an=0;
        for(var f=0;
        f<ao.length;f++)
        {
            an+=parseFloat(Q(am,ao[f]))||0
        }
        var c=parseFloat(Q(am,"width"))||((am.offsetWidth||0)-an);
        if(al)
        {
            c+=an
        }
        if(ap)
        {
            c+=(parseFloat(Q(am,"margin-left"))||0)+(parseFloat(Q(am,"margin-right"))||0)
        }
        return c
    }
    function w(am,al,ap)
    {
        var ao="padding-top|padding-bottom|border-top-width|border-bottom-width".split("|");
        var an=0;
        for(var f=0;
        f<ao.length;f++)
        {
            an+=parseFloat(Q(am,ao[f]))||0
        }
        var c=parseFloat(Q(am,"height"))||((am.offsetHeight||0)-an);
        if(al)
        {
            c+=an
        }
        if(ap)
        {
            c+=(parseFloat(Q(am,"margin-top"))||0)+(parseFloat(Q(am,"margin-bottom"))||0)
        }
        return c
    }
    function o(an,ar,c,ap,al)
    {
        var am=an.find(">span,>div").get();
        M(am).css({position:"relative",visibility:"hidden"});
        an.show();
        for(var f in ar)
        {
            if(/\%/.test(ar[f]))
            {
                ar[f]=parseInt(ar[f])/100;  
                var aq=an.offset()[/left/.test(f)?"left":"top"];
                var at=/left/.test(f)?"width":"height";
                if(ar[f]<0)
                {
                    ar[f]*=aq
                }
                else
                {
                    ar[f]*=l[at]()-an[at]()-aq
                }
            }
        }
        M(am[0]).css({left:(ar.left1||0)+"px",top:(ar.top1||0)+"px"});
        M(am[1]).css({left:(ar.left2||0)+"px",top:(ar.top2||0)+"px"});
        var al=ar.duration||al;
        function ao(au)
        {
            var av=M(am[au]).css("opacity");
            M(am[au]).css({visibility:"visible"}).css({opacity:0}).animate({opacity:av},al,"easeOutCirc").animate({top:0,left:0},{duration:al,easing:(ar.easing||ap),queue:false})
        }
        ao(0);
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            ao(1)
        },al*(ar.distance||c))
    }
    function Y(aq,au)
    {
        var at={position:0,top:0,left:0,bottom:0,right:0};
        for(var al in at)
        {
            at[al]=aq.get(0).style[al]
        }
        aq.show();
        var ap={width:B(aq.get(0),1,1),height:w(aq.get(0),1,1),"float":aq.css("float"),overflow:"hidden",opacity:0};
        for(var al in at)
        {
            ap[al]=at[al]||Q(aq.get(0),al)
        }
        var f=M("<div></div>").css({fontSize:"100%",background:"transparent",border:"none",margin:0,padding:0});
        aq.wrap(f);
        f=aq.parent();
        if(aq.css("position")=="static")
        {
            f.css({position:"relative"});
            aq.css({position:"relative"})
        }
        else
        {
            M.extend(ap,{position:aq.css("position"),zIndex:aq.css("z-index")});
            aq.css({position:"absolute",top:0,left:0,right:"auto",bottom:"auto"})
        }
        f.css(ap).show();
        var ar=au.direction||"left";
        var am=(ar=="up"||ar=="down")?"top":"left";
        var an=(ar=="up"||ar=="left");
        var c=au.distance||(am=="top"?aq.outerHeight(true):aq.outerWidth(true));
        aq.css(am,an?(isNaN(c)?"-"+c:-c):c);
        var ao={};
        ao[am]=(an?"+=":"-=")+c;f.animate({opacity:1},{duration:au.duration,easing:au.easing});
        aq.animate(ao,{queue:false,duration:au.duration,easing:au.easing,complete:function()
        {
            aq.css(at);aq.parent().replaceWith(aq);
            if(au.complete)
            {
                au.complete()
            }
        }})
    }
    if(n.length||T.length)
    {
        e()
    }
    r(H);
    if(E.caption)
    {
        F(j[H])
    }
    if(E.stopOnHover)
    {
        this.bind("mouseover",function(c)
        {
            q();
            J=true;console.info(J)
        });
        this.bind("mouseout",function(c)
        {
            K();
            J=false;
            console.info(J)
        })
    }
    K(1);
    var L=l.find("audio").get(0);
    if(L)
    {
        if(window.Audio&&L.canPlayType&&L.canPlayType("audio/mp3"))
        {
            L.loop="loop";
            if(E.autoPlay)
            {
                L.autoplay="autoplay";
                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    L.play()
                },100)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            L=L.src;
            var W=L.substring(0,L.length-/[^\\\/]+$/.exec(L)[0].length);
            var m="wsSound"+Math.round(Math.random()*9999);
            M("<div>").appendTo(l).get(0).id=m;
            var s="wsSL"+Math.round(Math.random()*9999);
            window[s]={onInit:function(){}};
            swfobject.createSWF({data:W+"player_mp3_js.swf",width:"1",height:"1"},{allowScriptAccess:"always",loop:true,FlashVars:"listener="+s+"&loop=1&autoplay="+(E.autoPlay?1:0)+"&mp3="+L},m);
            L=0
        }
        l.bind("stop",function()
        {
            if(L)
            {
                L.pause()
            }
            else
            {
                M(m).SetVariable("method:pause","")
            }
        });
        l.bind("start",function()
        {
            if(L)
            {
                L.play()
            }
            else
            {
                M(m).SetVariable("method:play","")
            }
        })
    }
    i.wsStart=k;
    i.wsStop=y;
    if(E.playPause)
    {
        var h=M('<a href="#" class="ws_playpause"></a>');
        if(E.autoPlay)
        {
            h.addClass("ws_pause")
        }
        else
        {
            h.addClass("ws_play")
        }
        h.click(function()
        {
            E.autoPlay=!E.autoPlay;
            if(!E.autoPlay)
            {
                i.wsStop();
                h.removeClass("ws_pause");
                h.addClass("ws_play")
            }
            else
            {
                K();
                h.removeClass("ws_play");h.addClass("ws_pause")
            }
            return false
        });
        this.append(h)
    }
    function v()
    {
        l.css("fontSize",Math.max(Math.min((l.width()/E.width)||1,1)*10,6))
    }
    if(E.responsive)
    {
        M(v);M(window).on("load resize",v)
    }
    return this
}

jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing,
{
        easeInOutExpo:function(e,f,a,h,g)
        {
            if(f==0)
            {
                return a
            }
            if(f==g)
            {
                return a+h
            }
            if((f/=g/2)<1)
            {
                return h/2*Math.pow(2,10*(f-1))+a
            }
            return h/2*(-Math.pow(2,-10*--f)+2)+a
        },easeOutCirc:function(e,f,a,h,g)
        {
            return h*Math.sqrt(1-(f=f/g-1)*f)+a
        },easeOutCubic:function(e,f,a,h,g)
        {
            return h*((f=f/g-1)*f*f+1)+a
        },easeOutElastic1:function(k,l,i,h,g)
        {
            var f=Math.PI/2;
            var m=1.70158;
            var e=0;
            var j=h;
            if(l==0)
            {
                return i
            }
            if((l/=g)==1)
            {
                return i+h
            }
            if(!e)
            {
                e=g*0.3
            }
            if(j<Math.abs(h))
            {
                j=h;
                var m=e/4
            }
            else
            {
                var m=e/f*Math.asin(h/j)
            }
            return j*Math.pow(2,-10*l)*Math.sin((l*g-m)*f/e)+h+i
        },easeOutBack:function(e,f,a,i,h,g)
        {
            if(g==undefined)
            {
                g=1.70158
            }
            return i*((f=f/h-1)*f*((g+1)*f+g)+1)+a
        }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how chrome renders the animation, but it seems the problem is when the tiles are moving. 
I think that when moving them, and changing the opacity of those tiles, chrome doesn't render correctly the background as transparent, and it kinda makes it fully white, thus hiding the content under it.

I managed to fix this by setting the background almost transparent on each tile:

```
#wowslider-container1 > div.ws_effect > div {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.01);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Allyanora. It worked. There is no white background appearing anymore. Now I just got to check it in the apple safari browser.

Comment: I viewed the website in the apple safari browser and my navigation background color is a transparent white instead of the blue gradient it is suppose to be like displayed in the other browsers. I do not know why it is doing this. I think it is because of the wowslider. Can somebody help?

Comment: Safari renders differently the gradients, you should use a gradient generator when creating it because there are some missing styles that are not interpreted correctly. you can go at: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ and generate your vertical linear gradient from: #4970E3 to #121B3E, no inner colors and check the box on the right that supports ie9. Copy the styles generated to your navigation element and it should work. Edit: Also apply the style to other elements that use gradients, I saw that there is a button that's missing its background too.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be z-index issue, when slider animates it plays with position and z-index property causing trouble. Quick fix would be increase z-index of elements you want to show above fade effect.

```
#header, #main{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

also Please put this line End of css file so that other css wont override. going ahead You can also add background color to these elements so that slider particles wont show coming up from these Elements ex: header

Good Luck!

Comment: I just tested your suggestion and the header still flickers. Also the image behind the moving tiles is disappearing on animation.

Comment: Thanks @Allyanora there are few things as this slider is on other website we can just try to figure out problem but exact answer can be given only on actual code I found that http://wowslider.com/wordpress-gallery-plugin-grafito-seven-demo.html it works fine on chrome so issue has to be there in code. my one observation is in working example .ws_effect is getting filled up and empty on transition queue while in question URL its not happening so there might be some minor issue in implementation or library compatibility ad so on...